# Same html code, different behavior

Tags: html, css

See demo here:
http://jsfiddle.net/Liber/4w0cye36/

```
<div style="width: 200px;"><a href="#">dontcomsssssssssssse</a><a href="#">dontomsssssssssssse</a></div>

<br />

<div style="width: 200px;">
    <a href="#">dontcomsssssssssssse</a>
    <a href="#">dontomsssssssssssse</a>
</div>
```

The first code:
result the links in only one line.

But the second code:
result the links in two different lines.

I just do some Enter within the second code to let it looks better, but why they got the different behavior ?

I just want the behavior of the second, but I'm using code compression that will result the wrong behavior like the first code.

Comment: there doesnt appear to be any code or images in your question

Comment: where is your code? hard to understand anything

Comment: downvote - no code provided, no clear problem describe, no taken attemps to resolve provided.

Comment: "Links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code." Very ridiculous feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `display:block` to your links. See solution [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4w0cye36/1/).
`<a>` default behavior is inline, so every text modification like new lines (first code) change visual result of element. With block display `a` gonna take all the width of his parent.

```
a { display: block; }
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I just curious, I only did some Enter to looks better, but why it will change visual result of element ? Is it a bug of HTML ?

Comment: It's because of space between end of div declaration > and start of link < who creates new line. Be careful with that. If one day you need to reproduce a special behavior like this one take look at <pre> element https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre

Comment: What I want is `<a>` display `inline`, and both of the codes behaviors the same like the second code.

Comment: display: inline-block; so :)

Comment: Well, thank you, I'll forget the browser which do not support `display: inline-block`

Comment: When you have a question about compatibility Can i use http://caniuse.com/ it's a place to be http://caniuse.com/#search=inline-block -> everybody since IE8